# C# How to stop code executing when a messagebox line appears

Tags: c#, winforms

```
                if (shaftPdfCB.Checked == true)
                {
                    Operation.RunMacro("shaftCheck.cs");
                    if (SelectedDrawings.GetSize() == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error, no shaft drawings to export.");
                        loadingLbl.Hide();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Operation.RunMacro("ExportShaft2.cs");
                    }
                }

                if (platePdfCB.Checked == true)
                {
                    Operation.RunMacro("plateCheck.cs");

                    if (SelectedDrawings.GetSize() == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error, no plate drawings to export.");
                        loadingLbl.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Operation.RunMacro("ExportPlate.cs");
                    }
                }
```

So when I run this code both of these will run, I would like it so it would stop when the loadingLbl.Hide(); line is hit, I dont want the application to exit I just want it so if the label hides no other code will be executed, what code do I need to achieve this?

Comment: You could use `return` te exit the current method or put a `else` before the second `if` statement.

Comment: return; has done the trick, thank you!

Comment: The `else` suggested by Jeroen would be my choice, it will make the code more readable then a return